# class added to element in directive, but not reflecting on page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Following is the code inside my directive.

```
template: '<button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-2x"></i></button>'
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    elem.bind('click', function() {
        elem.find('button').addClass('btn-success');
    });
}
```

In the console it shows that the class has been added to the element.
But does not reflect on page.

Comment: please create demo that replicates problem. STatement that you can see change in console but not in page doesn't really make a lot of sense

Comment: i tried to replicate the issue in plunker, after removing my firebase calls. it works fine. However, I found out that it applies the class once and then removes it instantly. What could possibly be the reason for that?

Comment: probably a digest cycle as a result of model changes. You really should use `ng-class` bound to scope model. It is rare in angular to use your own event handlers. Use `ng-click` also

Comment: But isn't it a good practice to use directives whenever we need to manipulate DOM?

Comment: but angular already has the directives built in for what you are doing and your changes can easily be over ridden by an angular digest. Let angular manipulate the DOM for you unless you have something that angular can't handle

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS does not react to added classes at runtime. You need to compile the element with the new class for it to work, try this:

```
app.directive('MyButton', function($compile)
    return {
        template: ...
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('click', function() {
                elem.find('button').addClass('btn-success');
                $compile(elem)(scope);
            });
        },
    };
});
```